# Creating a "web service" using ASP.net - what's in the DLL?

Tags: asp.net

All,

Sorry in advance - I'm a **total novice** when it comes to ASP.net.

I'm working on a project that's fairly simple. I have single HTML page that collects input from the user. When the input is complete - the html page uses AJAX to post the data to a web service. That service receives the data, does some processing on it, then sends back a response.

The "client" part of this app is pure HTML/Javascript (not ASP.net), and is complete and works perfectly.

The "service" part of this app (MyHandler.ashx) is built using ASP.net. Technically - what it does is receive data from the AJAX post. It then uses `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to open an Excel spreadsheet, pass the users' inputs **into** that spreadsheet, then retrieve several calculated values **from** the spreadsheet, and returns those values in the response to the AJAX post.

Using Visual Studio VS I've got this whole process running locally on my PC.

When I "publish" the project - VS creates a ton of files. I sent those files to the team that manages the server; they deployed them, and voilà - it works. (The necessary Office interop libraries are installed on the server).

So - my question - as I make a few modest changes (e.g., validation, error handling) to the handler - MyHandler.ashx - which of those published files actually change? If i want to reploy - do I simply need to resend an updated version of MyHandler.ashx? Or, do simple coding changes to that file require changes to the DLL?

I guess my question is, generally - what's **in** the DLL? (E.g., is it a compiled version of MyHandler.ashx?)

More specifically - publishing my project creates the following files that I don't really understand:

- Web.config
- Global.asax (in my project, there's not much in here)
- bin/MyProject.dll

So, if I make changes to MyHandler.ashx - can I simply reploy THAT file? Or, do I need to "publish", then "redeploy" thd dll? (By changes - I mean simple code changes, not decisions to include/exclude other external dependencies).

Sorry - this question must seem like nonsense to knowledgeable ASP.net developers. But, with other technologies I've used, things were clear:

- If you're developing a Flash project, you write source code in .FLA files, then compile, then deploy the resulting .SWF files.
- If you're developing an HTML/JavaScript/PHP project, you write those files, then deploy those same files

I'd trying to get a better understanding of what's what with ASP.net.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLL contains the compiled code behind the `ASHX` file. The `ASHX` is just a service definition for an HTTP handler. When you make changes to the service (e.g. the code), simply issue another **Publish** like you did before and send the entire package.

But in short, when you change the code, the DLL is what's changing.

Comment: thanks for you response. Is it fair to say this... If I have an HTML page that sends an AJAX post to "MyHandler.ashx" - the web server doesn't actually "run" MyHandler.ashx - it runs the "compiled version" in MyHandler.dll? By contrast - if MyHandler was written in PHP, then the web server would actually "run" the PHP file itself?

Comment: Thanks again, Michael. I'm not sure if you can answer this, but in my specific case - this means I need to publish the MyHandler.ashx, and /bin/MyHandler.dll. What about `Web.config` and `Global.asax`? (I know they don't change when I make minor code changes to MyHandler.ashx, so I don't need to ***republish*** them each time), but are they actually needed ***at all*** to run MyHandler?

Comment: They are in fact necessary files, so leave them in the published folder, but you are correct that they don't change ***every time*** you make changes.

Comment: what if we don't want those changes to be in dll and to execute script from source code directly?

Comment: @Anjum, if you want to execute code dynamically you're going to have to use something like Roslyn.

Comment: sorry, i don't get you

Comment: @Anjum, Roslyn is .NET's answer to dynamic code execution. Generally speaking all .NET code must be compiled and then executed. With Roslyn, and I speak on a very cursory level here, it's compiled at runtime and then executed. You could ideally feed Roslyn some compilable code and execute it.